# scoring system in a sprite kit game

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in sprite kit where a ball falls onto a person and i need to add a label which counts up every time the ball hits the man. I have the contact part sorted but i'm just a bit confused as to how to do the label and make it count up. GG

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKSpriteNode *firstNode, *secondNode;

    firstNode = (SKSpriteNode *)contact.bodyA.node;
    secondNode = (SKSpriteNode *)contact.bodyB.node;

    if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == manCategory)
    && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == pooCategory))
    {
        CGPoint contactPoint = contact.contactPoint;

        float contact_y = contactPoint.y;
        float target_y = secondNode.position.y;
        float margin = secondNode.frame.size.height/2 - 25;

        if ((contact_y > (target_y - margin)) &&
        (contact_y < (target_y + margin)))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show a bit of detail of how you're doing the contact stuff?

Comment: thats basically it...

Answer (score 3):

While you absolutely can still use UILabels and UIButtons for spriteKit, they seem to want you to use SKLabelNode instead.

An example of how to completely set up a SKLabelNode might look like:

```
@property SKLabelNode* deathLabel;
```

and then

```
deathLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"CoolveticaRg-Regular"];
deathLabel.fontSize = 16;
deathLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Deaths",deaths];
deathLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,labelHeight);
deathLabel.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
deathLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;
[hudLayer addChild:deathLabel];
```

and then when you need to update it, merely repeat the line:

```
deathLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Deaths",deaths];
```

one oddity I've noticed is that SKLabelNodes default to whatever font, fontSize, fontColor, horizontalAlignmentMode, and verticalAlignmentMode was last used, which is somewhere between convenient and frustrating, depending on how varied you want your labels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Make a UILabel Property...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *coreLabel;
```

Construct it...

```
scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
scoreLabel.text = @"0";
[self.view addSubview:scoreLabel];
```

...

update UIlabel...

```
if ((contact_y > (target_y - margin)) && (contact_y < (target_y + margin)))
    {
        int temp = [scoreLabel intValue];
        temp += 1;
        scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", temp];
    }
```